# (Done) Re-Open question on quitting internship due to transport costs

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Is it worth to quit my internship after first day?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120092/is-it-worth-to-quit-my-internship-after-first-day)

As originally worded this was clearly a close candidate under "specific choice", however I've edited it to a (hopefully) more SE-friendly format.

IMO it's now worth re-opening as it essentially becomes "costs for getting to/doing work higher than expected, any options other than to quit?" which is something that could apply quite generally.

Comment: Good edit. I voted to reopen already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just cast the 5th reopen vote.